# MVC viewModel user defined fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following:

```
public class myViewModel
{
  [DisplayName("User ID")]
  [DataType("string")]
  public MyCustomDataType UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to define MyCustomDataType as a user defined data type and have my getter and setter handle the data based on DataType. ie: if string, return string...etc.
How can I define MyCustomDataType so that it is aware of field's DataType?
And how would I define the getter and setter?

The reason behind this is I want to mask certain fields that contain senstive data. This is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388541/encrypt-data-passed-in-view-model)

Comment: Add some pseudo code to clarify, show how it should operate. Currently it is unclear.

Comment: I don’t want the viewModel to contain the actual UserID value. What Im looking to accomplish is to use the session as a transition to store and retrieve the data fields So my custom data type would look something like this. 

    Public class MyCustomDateType 
    { 
    get 
    { //use the token to get actual value from session. 
    //Cast value using DataType defined in ViewModel //return value } set { //store value in a custom session module which returns a token } } </pre>

Comment: Sorry I cant seem to figure out how to format the code block

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `[DataType]`.

All you need to do is to create an [editor template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx), which is used for forms, and a display template (which is used to display your custom data type).

You can say that they are custom views which will be included automatically when you use `Html.DisplayFor` and `Html.EditorFor` in your regular views.

Comment: I dont understand how this is going to help me? Im trying to manipulate the viewmodel data before it gets posted